# UWP Element Page.BottomAppTab Makes Page.Content Inaccessible

Tags: uwp-xaml

***New information - changing the `Page.BottomAppTab` to `Sticky="True` ([documentation for `AppBar.IsSticky`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbar.issticky?view=winrt-22621)) makes this problem go away.  So the new question is why?  Looking at the documentation the relationship is not clear.  If you can answer this new question I will upvote.  Thanks -RCHF***

---

UWP app works great on startup. `Page.Content` with `Page.TopAppBar` accepts clicks and gets cursor focus on startup.

Problems happen when `Page.BottomAppBar` is added.  The content of the `Page.BottomAppBar` displays fine and both `Page.TopAppBar` and `Page.BottomAppBar` accepts clicks.  ***But now the previously working `Page.Content` cannot be clicked on and doesn't get focus on startup.***

Running Visual Studio debugger I can comment out the `Page.BottomAppBar` XAML and `Page.Content` becomes clickable again in the running UWP app.

... in the Remarks section.

Here is the Visual Tree (left) and relevant `MainPage.xaml` (right)...

[image]

... *sorry about the size.*

The app starts with `spRegisterScreen1` which you see here...

[image]

...with red box labeled "1" being the `Page.TopAppBar` and the red box labeled "2" being the `Page.BottomAppBar`.  In the middle is the `Page.Content` composed of a `grid` holding the `spRegisterScreen1` `StackPanel` and the "Your Name" field.  It is this field which cannot be selected/clicked when the XAML includes `Page.BottomAppBar`.

Been reading around and I did find documentation saying ...

["In XAML, make sure you specify the `Page.BottomAppBar` property element in the same area as other property elements that may already be defined, like `Page.TopAppBar` or `Page.Resources`. The XAML language enforces that you can't mix the property elements between the XAML content that is setting Content, such as the typical root Grid element."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.page.bottomappbar?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1)

Pointers to clearer documentation are most welcome.

**QUESTION: How can I have a `Page.BottomAppBar` and also have clickable `Page.Content` elements that get focus on startup?**

Thanks!

Comment: Sharing some code will be better.

Comment: I was thinking this would be something obvious I missed about Page.BottomAppTab; but I can include what I hope are relevant parts of the XAML and the Visual Tree.  Maybe that will help.

Comment: @Ax1le - I have updated with screenshots.

Comment: Share [mcve] or code directly, not just a screenshoot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this problem lies in the [`AppBar.IsSticky` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbar.issticky?view=winrt-22621).  When `<Page.BottomAppBar IsSticky="False" ...` then the `Page.Content` is covered by an invisible screen element (I think) blocking mouse clicks.  It is still possible to TAB out of the `BottomAppBar and *under* the overlying element to the TAB-able` Page.Content` elements.

Setting `<Page.BottomAppBar IsSticky="True" ...` works and the mouseclicks register on the `Page.Content` as expected.